# stop further date conversion which is already in UTC

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

By default any date/timestamp stored in postgres is in standard UTC. Postgres has the `DATE` column type that stores only the date part of a full `timestamp`.

When using typeorm for postgres, and using the [`repositories`](https://typeorm.io/working-with-repository) the date is fetched as is. Yet, when you do something with a raw query like this:

```
const queryRunner = await this.connection.createQueryRunner();
await queryRunner.connect()
const response = await queryRunner.query('SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW WHERE AGE=23');
```

For the same date(only) column I receive something like this, which has its value as '1999-01-02'

```
{
  name: 'mleko',
  age : '23',
  dob : '1999-01-01:T22:00:00:000Z',
  address: 'xyz'
}
```

I'm not sure where exactly is this conversion taking place, probably the underlying driver that typeorm uses, yet, how do I tell typeorm to not do this conversion for a date already in UTC into again a UTC.

Comment: What is the PostgreSQL data type of the column?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , it's only date

Comment: This is just because javascript has such a weak type system. There is no "Date" type in javascript (it is called "Date" but does not represent dates) and most date/time libraries don't introduce one. There may be a more grown-up library in typescript.

Comment: @RichardHuxton  , do you think there is a workaround for this without resolving to a different orm?

Comment: 1) This "By default any date/timestamp stored in postgres is in standard UTC." is wrong. That only applies to `timestamp with time zone`. 2) A `date` does not have a time zone so something is turning your date value into a timestamp.

Comment: Sorry @mleko I'm not really a javascript dev but everything I've ever come across just offers datetime/timestamp and nothing more sophisticated.

Comment: Might want to look at [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon) and [TS(typescript)Luxon](https://github.com/tonysamperi/ts-luxon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the way I got around this was doing a cast on the raw query:

```
const queryRunner = await this.connection.createQueryRunner();
await queryRunner.connect()
const response = await queryRunner.query('SELECT name, age, dob::VARCHAR, address FROM MY_VIEW WHERE AGE=23');
```

this would avoid any conversions